# Yii2 custom delete ActionColumn alert twice

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a custom action column with just the delete button:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{delete}',
    'buttons' => [
        'delete' => function($url, $data){
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', ['orders-lines/delete', 'id' => $data->id], [
                'data' => [
                    'confirm' => Yii::t('app', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'),
                    'method' => 'post',
                ],
            ]);
        }
    ]
],
```

and whenever i click the trash icon, then accept the alert box, the same alert box is triggered again so I have to accept twice the alert box.

What could i be missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you got pjax there? If so could you check if the same happens if you add `'pjax' => '0',` to the `'data'` array?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im not using pjax and I get the same behaviour by setting pjax = 0

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
'template' => '{delete}',
                                    'buttons' => [
                                        'delete' => function ($url, $data) {
                                            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Delete"></span>', ['orders-lines/delete', 'id' => $data->id], ["data-pjax" => 0, 'onClick' => 'return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?") ']);
                                        },
                                            ],
                                        ],
```

Comment: what is the point in adding same answer twice, what is different here. it's already answered by **Bizley** in comment

Comment: setting it to an onClick event works but... is this due to a issue with 'confirm' method in yii? i need id value to be sent as a POST request